# Typescript: type that returns functions of a given type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that returns the functions of its generic type argument. It should behave like `keyof` but return only the keys that are used to call functions

I am using typescript 3.4.5.

Use Case:

```js
type FunctionOf<T> = ... // <-- what I want

function testFunction<T, U extends FunctionOf<T>>(obj: T, functionName: U): T[U] { 
  return obj[functionName]();
}
```

My specific case:

```js
export type Mapper<T, U> = (value: T, index?: number, array?: T[]) => U;

type IsFunction<T> = T extends Function ? T & Function : never;

export function toField<T, U extends keyof T, V extends IsFunction<T[U]>>(key: U): Mapper<T, V extends () => infer R ? R : never> {
    return (value: T) => (value[key] as V)();
}

class Test {
    x: string;
    constructor(x: string) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    getX(): string { return this.x; }
}

const y: Test[] = [new Test('hello')];

y.map(toField('getX')); // putting in 'x' will not cause the entire return to be never which is what I want.
```

I expect the above to restrict the accepted arguments to just the functions of `Test` but it doesn't

EDIT: I may have found a solution, but only when I use 'any' (I have no-unsafe-any as a rule). This correctly infers that the return type should be `never` when the field provided is not a function, but doesn't cause any compile errors. While this fixes my specific case, I'd still like to find a way of typing this more efficiently

```js
export type Mapper<T, U> = (value: T, index?: number, array?: T[]) => U;

type IsFunction<T> = T extends Function ? T & Function : never;

export function toField<T, U extends keyof T, V extends IsFunction<T[U]>>(
    key: U
): V extends Function ? Mapper<T, V extends () => infer R ? R : never> : never {
    return ((value: T) => (value[key] as V)()) as any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about this:

```
function toField<K extends keyof any>(key: K) {
  return <T extends Record<K, () => any>>(value: T): ReturnType<T[K]> => value[key]();
}
```

Here, `toField()` is a generic function in `K`, the type of the `key` argument, which *returns* a generic function in `T`, the type of the `value` argument.  `T` is constrained to types have a property with key `K`, whose property value at that key is a zero-argument function.  *That* function returns a value of type `ReturnType<T[K]>`, where `ReturnType<F>` is [defined in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1481-L1484) to be the type of the return type of a function type `F`.

Let's test it out:

```
class Test {
  x: string;
  constructor(x: string) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  getX(): string { return this.x; }
}

const y: Test[] = [new Test('hello')];
const strings = y.map(toField('getX')); // okay, string[]
const doesntWork = y.map(toField('x')); // error!
//                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
// y.map() doesn't accept a toField('x'), since Test['x'] is not a zero arg fn
```

I assume it's better that `y.map(toField('x'))` should be a compile-time warning and not silently produce a value of type `never[]` at compile time.  You don't want to pass `toField('x')` to `y.map()` at all.

A few more cases:

```
const thisWorks = toField('toLowerCase')("LOWERCASE");
const thisDoesnt = toField('charAt')("oops"); // error!
//                                   ~~~~~~
// "oops".charAt is a function but needs args
```

You can call `"LOWERCASE".toLowerCase()`, but shouldn't can't call `"oops".charAt()`.

Finally, note that your original typings really only worked in one line like `arr.map(toField("xxx"))` because it relied on [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of `arr.map()` to infer the generic type parameters in `toField()`.  You'd run into trouble doing this:

```
const getXField = toField('getX');
// const getXField: <T extends Record<"getX", () => any>>(value: T) => ReturnType<T["getX"]>
const stringsTwoStep = y.map(getXField); // okay, string[]
```

For your original code, the first line would be an error because it would fail to infer anything for `T`, default to `{}` or `unknown`, and then end up constraining `U` to `never`, and `'getX'` is not assignable to `never`.  Blegh.  But in the above code there's no difference between calling it in one line or splitting it into two.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20toField%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20any%3E%28key%3A%20K%29%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3CT%20extends%20Record%3CK%2C%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%3E%28value%3A%20T%29%3A%20ReturnType%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%3D%3E%20value%5Bkey%5D%28%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20x%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20constructor%28x%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20getX%28%29%3A%20string%20%7B%20return%20this.x%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20y%3A%20Test%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20Test%28%27hello%27%29%5D%3B%0Aconst%20strings%20%3D%20y.map%28toField%28%27getX%27%29%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%2C%20string%5B%5D%0Aconst%20doesntWork%20%3D%20y.map%28toField%28%27x%27%29%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%21%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20~~~~~~~~~~~~%20%0A%2F%2F%20y.map%28%29%20doesn%27t%20accept%20a%20toField%28%27x%27%29%2C%20since%20Test%5B%27x%27%5D%20is%20not%20a%20zero%20arg%20fn%0A%0Aconst%20thisWorks%20%3D%20toField%28%27toLowerCase%27%29%28%22LOWERCASE%22%29%3B%0Aconst%20thisDoesnt%20%3D%20toField%28%27charAt%27%29%28%22oops%22%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%21%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20~~~~~~%0A%2F%2F%20%22oops%22.charAt%20is%20a%20function%20but%20needs%20args%20%0A%0A%2F%2F%20can%20also%20do%20this%20in%20two%20steps%3A%0Aconst%20getXField%20%3D%20toField%28%27getX%27%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20const%20getXField%3A%20%3CT%20extends%20Record%3C%22getX%22%2C%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%3E%28value%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20ReturnType%3CT%5B%22getX%22%5D%3E%0Aconst%20stringsTwoStep%20%3D%20y.map%28getXField%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%2C%20string%5B%5D%0A%0A)